# Boost asio bind read handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to bind a read handler, and boost asio is driving me crazy.

I have the following class

```
class namenode_registration: 
        public  boost::enable_shared_from_this<namenode_registration>,
        private boost::noncopyable {
private:
     [...]
public:
    namenode_registration(....);
    [...]
    void handle_request_sent(const boost::system::error_code& e);
    void handle_read_reply_type(boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1& buffer,
        const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
};
```

With the following implementation :

```
void namenode_registration::handle_request_sent(
        const boost::system::error_code& e) {
    if (!e) {
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
                boost::asio::buffer(buffer_data_, namenode::reply::type_size),
                boost::bind(&namenode_registration::handle_read_reply_type,
                        shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

And I really can't understand why it does not compile :

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                from /home/.../datanode/namenode_registration.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:
    In instantiation of ‘boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified,
    void (datanode::namenode_registration::*)(boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1&,
    const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int)>’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:15:48:
    instantiated from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (datanode::namenode_registration::*
    (boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1&, const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int),
    boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<datanode::namenode_registration> >,
    boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >’
/home/.../datanode/namenode_registration.cpp:50:51:
    instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37:
    erreur: ‘void (datanode::namenode_registration::*)(boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1&,
    const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't bound enough arguments for this function:

```
void handle_read_reply_type(boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1& buffer,
    const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
```

You're missing the buffer argument:

```
            boost::bind(&namenode_registration::handle_read_reply_type,
                    shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Comment: Oh god, you're absolutely right ! I have been struggling with it for one hour. Sorry for asking such a stupid question...